# Updating multiple firestone collections

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update 2 firebase collections that will contain an array element that is the same.

For example, I'm building a job app, so when a user creates a job, it pushes that job object into a firebase collection called alljobs under a document called alljobs. In addition, the same job is pushed to a firebase collection called created jobs. Where each user on the app has their individual created jobs, each doc is named the users id.
Is there an easy way to update this specific job in both alljobs collection and the createdjobs collection?

For example, my approach of doing it would be like this.

```
Individual Job component (obtained by previously mapping through all the jobs)

const [userjobs, setUserjobs] = useState([])
const {job, createdjobs} = props
function updateJob(){
   createdjobs?.map(job1=>{
     if(job1.jobid===job.jobid){
      const jobindex = createdjobs.indexOf(job1)
      
      createdjobs[jobindex].jobtitle = 'New title'
      
      db.collection('createdjobs').doc(user.uid).update({
        jobs: createdjobs
      })
   }
  })
}
```

I'll basically have to repeat this same process to update once again the job that has just been updated in the createdjobs collection. This gets repetitive and messy. So looking for a solution to this. By mapping through alljobs this time.

```
 useEffect(()=>{

  db.collection('alljobs').doc('alljobs').onSnapshot(snap=>{
    setAlljobs(snap.data().jobs)
  })

},[])
```

Comment: So basically you want to update the `createdJob` collection when changing `alljobs` collection or vice versa or both??

Comment: update alljobs, when createdjobs is updated

Answer (score 1):

As @Thanh Le suggested you can write a `Google Cloud Function` to fulfill this purpose. In cloud functions there is a function type named triggers. You can use this triggers.

### Cloud Function triggers

We can write functions which will automatically trigger when the specfied document or set of documents,

1. `onCreate` - Trigger when document creating
2. `onUpdate` - Triggered when a document already exists and has any value changed.
3. `onDelete` - Trigger when document deleting
4. `onWrite` - Triggered when `onCreate`, `onUpdate` or `onDelete` is triggered.

From these triggers you can use `onWrite` Trigger to to implement the function.

```
exports.updateAllJobsTrigger = functions.firestore.document('createdJob/{userId}')
    onWrite(async (change, context) => {
        // Check if document is deleted
        if (!change.after.exists) {
            logger.log('Document not existing. Function exited.');
            return;
        }

        const allJobsRef = admin.firestore().collection('alljobs').doc('alljobs');
        
        // Check if document created
        if (!change.before.exists) {
            try {
                // This is a newly created document. Therefore newjob should be in first element
                const newJob = change.after.data().jobs[0];
                const data = (await allJobsRef.get()).data();
                if (data) {
                    const jobs = data.jobs;
                    await allJobsRef.update({
                        jobs: [...jobs, newJob]
                    });
                    logger.info('Job added to All jobs queue.');
                }
            } catch (exception) {
                logger.error(exception)
            }

            return;
        }

        
        try {
            // This is a updating document.newly added job is in the last element of the array
            const newJob = change.after.data().jobs[change.after.data().jobs.length - 1];
            const data = (await allJobsRef.get()).data();
            if (data) {
                const jobs = data.jobs;
                await allJobsRef.update({
                    jobs: [...jobs, newJob]
                });
                logger.info('Job added to All jobs queue.');
            }
        } catch (exception) {
            logger.error(exception)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for your problem I think. But I suggest you to write a sync function to Firebase Function.
It will watch changes of one source and sync to others. So that your logic code only needs to manage one source of trust.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nimna Perera said, you can use Cloud Functions to solve this issue. Your CF should be triggered when a document is updated, created or deleted (so the onWrite option). Another way to do this is through [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), when you need to read and write the documents or [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) when you only need to write in one or various documents. In both cases you are not limited to a single collection, so it should work for your issue.